# Symfony: глобальный импорт bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, webpack, symfony

Мне необходимо подключить bootstrap 4 таким образом, чтобы он был виден во всех подключаемых javascript файлах.
Собственно, есть файл app.js, в котором подключается bootstrap:

```
const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

require('bootstrap');
```

Он прописан в webpack'e и вызывается в нужном мне html файле:

```
{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
```

Bootstrap заводится, все компоненты работают и даже плагины (по типу Modal, Tooltip и т.д.), но только ВНУТРИ app.js. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы эти плагины были видны для других JavaScript файлов.

Пробовал в нужном мне файле подключить нужные плагины отдельно:

```
require('bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip');
require('bootstrap/js/dist/modal');
```

Но таким образом весь функционал, связанный с этими компонентами, начинает срабатывать дважды, что выглядит неприятно и порой раздражает. Как можно подключить bootstrap так, чтобы функционал компонентов не дублировался и он был виден во всех JS файлах?

Вот ошибка на пример плагина Tooltip:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).tooltip is not a function TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://192.168.117.39:8000/build/aboninfo.f622ec28.js:225:45)
    at mightThrow (https://192.168.117.39:8000/build/aboninfo.f622ec28.js:5833:29)
    at process (https://192.168.117.39:8000/build/aboninfo.f622ec28.js:5901:12) undefined
```

Событие модального окна (плагин Modal) так вообще не срабатывает и никакой реакции на него нет:

```
$("#inetSessionListModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
...
});
```

Подключение файлов в Webpack:

```
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
.addEntry('aboninfo', './assets/js/aboninfo.js')
```

И в самом шаблоне:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }} // Здесь подключается app.js
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('aboninfo') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Приведите пример того, что не работает и как эти (дополнительные) скрипты подключаются

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: попробуйте вместо `global.$ = global.jQuery = $;` сделать `window.$ = window.jQuery = $;`

Comment: Все так же, ничего не изменилось

Comment: а `block javascripts` в начале html или в конце?

Comment: если попробовать `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { $("#inetSessionListModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {...}});`

Comment: Блок стоит в конце, однако и в начало пробовал, это вообще не меняет картины в целом.
Событие у меня и так вешается после загрузки страницы `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему следующим образом, прописав в нужном файле следующее:

```
const $ = global.jQuery;
```

И после этого все ивенты, которые были прикреплены к jQuery, подхватились в нужном мне файле.